# Count in people scope and User Profiles is different

Tags: user-profile-service, people-search

Can anybody tell me why item count in People Scope and User Profiles is different?

And at different time item count in Scope people can be different too. I mean at 11 a.m. it was 501 and at 4 p.m. it was 467 and now it is again 501!

Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number could change based on when your user profile sync is scheduled.  Profiles can be added or removed based on those sync schedules.

Then you have the crawl schedules where the profile changes will be reflected in the index.

It is possible that a crawl ran, but that something prevented it from reading all of the profiles, but that were picked up in a subsequent run.

Comment: Thank you! What may prevent crawling?

Comment: Oh I've found such message: "Deleted by the gatherer ( This item was deleted because the crawler did not encounter it during the last full crawl. )" 30 items were deleted today. And i'm sure they will appear soon again. Why does it happen?

Comment: I would review the FIM logs first to make sure that all of the items are being brought into the system during the sync process.